# How to comfortably monitor variables in a VBscript during development process? (e.g. in a continuously opened command window)

Tags: vbscript, scripting, cmd, notepad++, wsh

I need to write a huge **VBscript** to automatically run an application and I'm looking for a way to comfortably monitor what I'm actually doing, in other words, to display the values of some/all variables involved in my script.

I'm used to work with Matlab, where I have a comfortable workspace browser. When I run a Matlab script, all variables, their types and their values are accessible in that workspace and can be checked.

The VBscript I write with **Notepad++** (it needs to be a free editor) and the only way I found to display variables was echoing them via `wscript` and `cscript`.

---

I set up the **shortcuts.xml** with the following line to run my script directly from Notepad++:

```
<Command name="Run with CScript" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="116">cmd /K %windir%\system32\cscript.exe &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
```

In case I include commands in my script like

```
Wscript.Echo myVar
Wscript.Echo "Hello World!"
```

and run it with the newly introduced shortcut, a **cmd** window pops up and displays the value of myVar and "Hello World!".
But the next time I run the script a new window pops up. So my question is:

**Is it possible get a continuously opened output window, displaying all echoed values everytime I run a script?** I actually want to put the window on a second screen and keep the values from previous runs. So I can enter a line `Wscript.Echo something`, run, check, enter something else and so on, without fiddling around with a bunch of opened windows.

---

**Alternatively, is there any open-source/free editor which offers an accessible workspace like the one in Matlab?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The open-source editor [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) offers what I was looking for.**

[image]

The default settings in `vb.properties` enable a similar behavior like in Notepad++

```
command.build.$(file.patterns.wscript)=cscript "$(FilePath)"
command.build.subsystem.$(file.patterns.wscript)=1
```

One can change it as follows to get the output into the integrated console.

```
command.go.$(file.patterns.wscript)=cscript.exe //nologo "$(FilePath)"
command.go.subsystem.$(file.patterns.wscript)=0
```

<kbd>F5</kbd> runs the script and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> cleans the output.

---

Another option is the [NppExec](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/) Plugin for Notepad++ suggested by @Ansgar Wiechers, which adds a console. The script can be run with `cscript.exe /nologo "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` then.

Comment: That is not what you've been asking. Your code is simply echoing variables. You don't get a table with the values/types of all variables. The same result can be achieved in Notepad++ by installing the [NppExec](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/) plugin and running `cscript //nologo "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` in the console window.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers My questions was, and always was, "Is it possible to get a continuously opened output window, displaying all echoed values everytime I run a script?" - the other thing was a little extravaganza, with just a little hope that there is a solution. And thanks for the advice with the NppExec plugin - that could be an answer too.

Comment: Had you phrased your question like that I might have suggested SciTE right away (I've been using the editor for about 10 years). It was my understanding that you wanted to continuously track the state of your variables, for which you'd need a debugger. Anyway, glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Beginner to vbscript. Can you please give detailed steps for debugging vbscript (to track variables continuously) with notepad++ using cscript or wscript ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 Which part of "you need a debugger for that" requires further explanation? Notepad++ is an editor, not a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Use a debugger. Start your script with the (meta)option //X. If you are lucky, you already have installed software (MS Office, Visual Studio (Express)) that provides a debugger for VBScript. If not do a bit of research to find an Express version suitable to your OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can *almost* write native VBScript in the VBA editor, so if you have Excel or whatever you can use this to debug, then go through some steps to convert back to VBScript. That's what I usually do.

Comment: can you please show the steps or an example ? I can make a separate question for this if you'd like.

Comment: Basically you open the Excel VBA editor (many online guides on that), write your code. Then you remove all the type declarations and make everything late binding and you can run it in VBS. You most certainly will need to ask a new question, and if you do you need to _post example code_, and show some effort at understanding - i.e. prove that you tried to run it in VBS and what error you got and what effort you made to fix it. Otherwise it appears you're just asking for someone to convert your code for you